# Filter column on today's date.

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do is filter the data in the spreadsheet on Column W, then copy all rows from this sheet into another sheet if the value in Column N is equal to today's date.

Where I'm getting stuck is filtering the data in Column N to today's date in the macro. Below I chose a random data to see how it would look, what I'm trying to do is figure out if there is a way of making this automatically update to the current date without being manually changed. Or if I need to take another approach.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$3:$W$2012").AutoFilter Field:=13, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "1/20/2015")
```

The dates are formatted to ("ddd, date, mmmyy hh:mm -> Tue 20 Jan15  14:00) I only want it to filter based on the date not the time. I also don't want to change this format as its not a spreadsheet I created, its given to me updated each day.

I'm fairly new to vba so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work; it needn't be broken down into functions or the variables "todaysYear" etc but I did it so you can see how it all works.

```
Sub filter()
todaysDate = getTodaysDate()               'calls a function which prepares todays date in the format needed
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("N:W").AutoFilter
    .Range("N:W").AutoFilter field:=10, Criteria1:=">2"                'whatever your first criteria is (Column W)
    .Range("N:W").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & todaysDate & "*"
End With
ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).copy
Sheets("Sheet2").[a1].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues                       'Change to the name of the destination sheet
End Sub

Function getTodaysDate()
todayDay = WeekdayName(Weekday(Now), True)
todayDayDate = Weekday(Now)
todayMonth = MonthName(Month(Now), True)
todayYear = Mid(Year(Now), 3, 2)
getTodaysDate = todayDay & " " & todayDayDate & " " & todayMonth & todayYear
End Function
```

Comment: Had to do a bit of tweaking but this ended up working great. Thanks for the reply and sorry it took me so long to get back to you.

Comment: Consider voting this answer up if it was useful :)